# Issues with `cd` after `alias`

Tags: linux, cd

I read this command somewhere on Twitter and executed it in my Terminal and it seems it removed the `cd` package completely from the OS.

```
alias cd="say -v cello"
```

1. What does this command do? Can you breakup the explanation of this command?
2. How do I install `cd` back to Ubuntu?

Comment: Executing commands you don't understand is a bad idea.

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-bash-fork-bomb/

Comment: I dont know why the comment has been downvoted ? its quite a fun topic

Comment: Executing commands you don't know is a great idea, be curious! ;) Just beware of data loss!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. That command aliases `say -v cello` to `cd`, which means now `cd` is a shortcut for `say -v cello`
2. `cd` cannot be installed/uninstalled separately, it's part of the shell, not a separate program. Your problem is that you're shadowing the original `cd` with your alias `cd`. If you remove that alias (`unalias`), it should be back.

Answer (score 2):

You can unalias cd to get it working again. Here's the link: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/unalias.1posix.html

The required command will be: `unalias cd`

From what I gather, say is a text-to-speech convertor. Check it out here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TextToSpeech

Comment: Perhaps the same text-to-speech convertor can be used to read out the man page linked above.

Answer (score 2):

> **1. What does this command do? Can you breakup the explanation of this command?**

It creates an `alias`, remapping `cd` to mean `say -v cello`.

A useful example you could use this would be if you always wanted to recursively delete when using `rm`:

```
alias rm="rm -rf"
```

Or if you always want to say "yes" when using `yum`:

```
alias yum="yum -y"
```

---

> **2. How do I install `cd` back to Ubuntu?**

Run this command:

```
unalias cd
```

Comment: `rm="rm -rf"` Watch out about such alias... You'd better remember you have aliased it to be recursive. It's better to not shadow shell commands, and instead use something like `rmr` for recursive remove.